# Did Robb have a Hand of King in the North?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Did Robb Stark, who became King in the North, have a Hand? If so, who was it? And if not, was he waiting until the end of the war, or did he just want to have sole control of the kingdom?

I can't remember it being mentioned in the novels or TV series.

Comment: The North is a different place than the South. The custom of the hand is a Southern thing. Northmen do it themselves or not at all. Eddard taught this to his kids. When he executed the deserter from the wall himself and not let an executioner do it for him.

There is even a line he says after wich i cant remember now about not beeing like the southerners.

The hand is used as the Kings second. So the King can go hunting, horing, or doing whatever else that is not as boring as running a country.

Comment: @Cherubel, this should be an answer, also it's _whoring_ not _horing_.

Comment: @Cherubel it's not Southern thing, office of Hand of the King was introduced only after [AC](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Years_after_Aegon%27s_Conquest). [Orys Baratheon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Orys_Baratheon) was the first Hand of the King.

Comment: @NikaG. >this is known ;-)<. What I mean the Northmen have different belief system and customs. There never was a hand of a Northern king. Before Aegon came and made the Kings of the North bend the knee.

Comment: @Nika: So before Aegon kings didn't have any hands??? How did they eat their meals, or fight their battles? That sounds horrible!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the old Kings in the North did not have Hands. It is worth pointing out that the office of "Hand of the King" is a construct of the Targaryens. In "The World of Ice & Fire: The Untold History", Aegon the Conqueror created the first hand.

> And Orys Baratheon he proclaimed to be 'my shield, my stalwart, my strong right hand.' Thus Baratheon is reckoned by the maesters the first King's Hand.

There was not a Hand to the King in the North, nor was it likely there would be one.

Comment: +1. Also, as a matter of symbolism, *not* having a Hand was an easy way for Robb to signal to the Northerners that he was different from the kings on the Iron Throne.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit: The real reason that King Robb didn't have a Hand, is that Greatjon Umber needed it after Robb's "meat" was bloody tough and took half of his own hand out of commission!

Answer (score 6):

The North is a different place than the South. The custom of the Hand is a Southern thing. Northerners do something themselves or don't do it at all. Eddard taught this to his kids. When he executed the deserter from the wall himself rather than let an executioner do it for him. There is even a line he says afterwards (that I can't remember now) about not being like the Southerners.

The Hand is used as the Kings second, so the King is free to go hunting, whoring, or doing whatever else that is not as boring as running a country.

So to answer your question, no he didn't have a Hand nor did he wait to appoint one.